# Backbone Forms - Populating Checkboxes

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-forms

I have created a Backbone form for a model with the following schema (isolated checkboxes)

```
schema: ->
  departments:
      type: "Checkboxes"
      title: "Department(s)*"
      options: (new CPP.Collections.Departments) # Return ALL departments
```

The model's 'department' field is filled with a collection of the same type containing a subset of these departments.

For example if the schema options is a collection containing departments `[d1, d2, d3, d4]`, the @model.get('departments') could return a collection with `[d1, d3]`

However in my Backbone Form, all the checkboxes are blank, shouldn't those which refer to departments belonging to the model be checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Checkboxes form element populates values based on model ids, not models. In other words `@model.get('departments')` is expected to return `[1, 3]`.

Edit: [Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccwve/) that shows both a working and non-working version.

Comment: Are you sure? In the docs, I would expect it to work directly with collections since it inherits from 'Select' (though that's clearly not necessarily the case) - https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#select

Comment: @PeterHamilton - The docs are a bit ambiguous, but yes, I'm pretty sure. Check the fiddle I edited into my answer. In fact the `Select` element works the same way, doesn't it?

Comment: Hero, that works great (I wasn't at my machine to test before!)